# nuGet Package dependencies and project references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-spec

After publishing a new version of one of out nuGet packages we run into errors when running an application that consumes some of our packages.

Solution 1 contains the code for the packages that will be publsihed to nuGet.

- project A, version 1.0.0.0
- Project B, version 1.0.0.0 (has project reference to project A)
- Project C, version 1.0.0.0 (has project reference to project A)

for packages B en C the dependencies are explicit stated in a nuspec file:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency id="A" version="[1.0.0.0,]" />
</dependencies>
```

Solution 2 uses all 3 packages (in different projects).

New versions are made for project A and B and published as version 1.0.1.0. All changes are backward compatible. However, the projects that consume package C will not work with the newer version of A. Running it will throw a **'Could not load file or assembly'** error. It tries to load assemby A, version 1.0.0.0 - ignoring the dependency direction from the nuget spec.

Is this because a project reference was made in solution 1?

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? What is the error? Does not compile? Package C will not install?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: [Assembly binding redirections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/vstudio/2fc472t2(v=vs.100).aspx) should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, i know. I already added it. But i want to know why the dependency directions in the nuGet spec do not have effect and what i should do different to let package C work with a newer version of package A.